# Why isn't BS4 Scrollspy working correctly?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm having issues getting Bootstrap 4's Scrollspy to work. I've already checked the BS4 documentation and done a small Scrollspy tutorial on youtube but I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong. I'm currently using a CDN for BS4's CSS & JS files. Here is a link to a codepen: https://codepen.io/James-Goodwin/pen/QYpePq

```html
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#responsiveNav" data-offset="50">

  <header id="home">
    <!--Navbar-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
      <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand"><!--<img src="img/ShadeSetters-logo.png" alt="Shade Setters logo">-->ShadeSetters</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#responsiveNav">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="responsiveNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#content1">About</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#content2">Services</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#content3">Testimonials</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#content4">FAQ</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <section id="content1" class="container-fluid bg-success" style="padding-top:70px; padding-bottom: 70px">
    <h1>Content 1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima voluptatem, facilis, nisi harum qui quibusdam asperiores excepturi facere dolor eveniet enim praesentium voluptates. Recusandae, voluptatibus sed temporibus quidem, voluptatum veniam
      debitis error, sit id quod quae alias, expedita corporis soluta.</p>
  </section>

  <section id="content2" class="container-fluid bg-warning" style="padding-top:70px; padding-bottom: 70px">
    <h1>Content 2</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima voluptatem, facilis, nisi harum qui quibusdam asperiores excepturi facere dolor eveniet enim praesentium voluptates. Recusandae, voluptatibus sed temporibus quidem, voluptatum veniam
      debitis error, sit id quod quae alias, expedita corporis soluta.</p>
  </section>

  <section id="content3" class="container-fluid bg-primary" style="padding-top:70px; padding-bottom: 70px">
    <h1>Content 3</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima voluptatem, facilis, nisi harum qui quibusdam asperiores excepturi facere dolor eveniet enim praesentium voluptates. Recusandae, voluptatibus sed temporibus quidem, voluptatum veniam
      debitis error, sit id quod quae alias, expedita corporis soluta.</p>
  </section>

  <section id="content4" class="container-fluid bg-danger" style="padding-top:70px; padding-bottom: 70px">
    <h1>Content 4</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima voluptatem, facilis, nisi harum qui quibusdam asperiores excepturi facere dolor eveniet enim praesentium voluptates. Recusandae, voluptatibus sed temporibus quidem, voluptatum veniam
      debitis error, sit id quod quae alias, expedita corporis soluta.</p>
  </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it works. Maybe you forgot to add jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle?

Check the snippet below in full screen. I added more text to each section so you can see clearly.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#responsiveNav" data-offset="50">

  <header id="home">
    <!--Navbar-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
      <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand"><!--<img src="img/ShadeSetters-logo.png" alt="Shade Setters logo">-->ShadeSetters</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#responsiveNav">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="responsiveNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#content1">About</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#content2">Services</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#content3">Testimonials</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#content4">FAQ</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <section id="content1" class="container-fluid bg-success" style="padding-top:70px; padding-bottom: 70px">
    <h1>Content 1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima voluptatem, facilis, nisi harum qui quibusdam asperiores excepturi facere dolor eveniet enim praesentium voluptates. Recusandae, voluptatibus sed temporibus quidem, voluptatum veniam debitis error, sit id quod quae alias, expedita corporis soluta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima voluptatem, facilis, nisi harum qui quibusdam asperiores excepturi facere dolor eveniet enim praesentium voluptates. Recusandae, voluptatibus sed temporibus quidem, voluptatum veniam debitis error, sit id quod quae alias, expedita corporis soluta.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima voluptatem, facilis, nisi harum qui quibusdam asperiores excepturi facere dolor eveniet enim praesentium voluptates. Recusandae, voluptatibus sed temporibus quidem, voluptatum veniam debitis error, sit id quod quae alias, expedita corporis soluta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima voluptatem, facilis, nisi harum qui quibusdam asperiores excepturi facere dolor eveniet enim praesentium voluptates. Recusandae, voluptatibus sed temporibus quidem, voluptatum veniam debitis error, sit id quod quae alias, expedita corporis soluta.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima voluptatem, facilis, nisi harum qui quibusdam asperiores excepturi facere dolor eveniet enim praesentium voluptates. Recusandae, voluptatibus sed temporibus quidem, voluptatum veniam debitis error, sit id quod quae alias, expedita corporis soluta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima voluptatem, facilis, nisi harum qui quibusdam asperiores excepturi facere dolor eveniet enim praesentium voluptates. Recusandae, voluptatibus sed temporibus quidem, voluptatum veniam debitis error, sit id quod quae alias, expedita corporis soluta.</p>
  </section>

  <section id="content2" class="container-fluid bg-warning" style="padding-top:70px; padding-bottom: 70px">
    <h1>Content 2</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima voluptatem, facilis, nisi harum qui quibusdam asperiores excepturi facere dolor eveniet enim praesentium voluptates. Recusandae, voluptatibus sed temporibus quidem, voluptatum veniam debitis error, sit id quod quae alias, expedita corporis soluta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima voluptatem, facilis, nisi harum qui quibusdam asperiores excepturi facere dolor eveniet enim praesentium voluptates. Recusandae, voluptatibus sed temporibus quidem, voluptatum veniam debitis error, sit id quod quae alias, expedita corporis soluta.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima voluptatem, facilis, nisi harum qui quibusdam asperiores excepturi facere dolor eveniet enim praesentium voluptates. Recusandae, voluptatibus sed temporibus quidem, voluptatum veniam debitis error, sit id quod quae alias, expedita corporis soluta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima voluptatem, facilis, nisi harum qui quibusdam asperiores excepturi facere dolor eveniet enim praesentium voluptates. Recusandae, voluptatibus sed temporibus quidem, voluptatum veniam debitis error, sit id quod quae alias, expedita corporis soluta.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima voluptatem, facilis, nisi harum qui quibusdam asperiores excepturi facere dolor eveniet enim praesentium voluptates. Recusandae, voluptatibus sed temporibus quidem, voluptatum veniam debitis error, sit id quod quae alias, expedita corporis soluta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima voluptatem, facilis, nisi harum qui quibusdam asperiores excepturi facere dolor eveniet enim praesentium voluptates. Recusandae, voluptatibus sed temporibus quidem, voluptatum veniam debitis error, sit id quod quae alias, expedita corporis soluta.</p>
  </section>

  <section id="content3" class="container-fluid bg-primary" style="padding-top:70px; padding-bottom: 70px">
    <h1>Content 3</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima voluptatem, facilis, nisi harum qui quibusdam asperiores excepturi facere dolor eveniet enim praesentium voluptates. Recusandae, voluptatibus sed temporibus quidem, voluptatum veniam debitis error, sit id quod quae alias, expedita corporis soluta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima voluptatem, facilis, nisi harum qui quibusdam asperiores excepturi facere dolor eveniet enim praesentium voluptates. Recusandae, voluptatibus sed temporibus quidem, voluptatum veniam debitis error, sit id quod quae alias, expedita corporis soluta.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima voluptatem, facilis, nisi harum qui quibusdam asperiores excepturi facere dolor eveniet enim praesentium voluptates. Recusandae, voluptatibus sed temporibus quidem, voluptatum veniam debitis error, sit id quod quae alias, expedita corporis soluta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima voluptatem, facilis, nisi harum qui quibusdam asperiores excepturi facere dolor eveniet enim praesentium voluptates. Recusandae, voluptatibus sed temporibus quidem, voluptatum veniam debitis error, sit id quod quae alias, expedita corporis soluta.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima voluptatem, facilis, nisi harum qui quibusdam asperiores excepturi facere dolor eveniet enim praesentium voluptates. Recusandae, voluptatibus sed temporibus quidem, voluptatum veniam debitis error, sit id quod quae alias, expedita corporis soluta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima voluptatem, facilis, nisi harum qui quibusdam asperiores excepturi facere dolor eveniet enim praesentium voluptates. Recusandae, voluptatibus sed temporibus quidem, voluptatum veniam debitis error, sit id quod quae alias, expedita corporis soluta.</p>
  </section>

  <section id="content4" class="container-fluid bg-danger" style="padding-top:70px; padding-bottom: 70px">
    <h1>Content 4</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima voluptatem, facilis, nisi harum qui quibusdam asperiores excepturi facere dolor eveniet enim praesentium voluptates. Recusandae, voluptatibus sed temporibus quidem, voluptatum veniam debitis error, sit id quod quae alias, expedita corporis soluta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima voluptatem, facilis, nisi harum qui quibusdam asperiores excepturi facere dolor eveniet enim praesentium voluptates. Recusandae, voluptatibus sed temporibus quidem, voluptatum veniam debitis error, sit id quod quae alias, expedita corporis soluta.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima voluptatem, facilis, nisi harum qui quibusdam asperiores excepturi facere dolor eveniet enim praesentium voluptates. Recusandae, voluptatibus sed temporibus quidem, voluptatum veniam debitis error, sit id quod quae alias, expedita corporis soluta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima voluptatem, facilis, nisi harum qui quibusdam asperiores excepturi facere dolor eveniet enim praesentium voluptates. Recusandae, voluptatibus sed temporibus quidem, voluptatum veniam debitis error, sit id quod quae alias, expedita corporis soluta.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima voluptatem, facilis, nisi harum qui quibusdam asperiores excepturi facere dolor eveniet enim praesentium voluptates. Recusandae, voluptatibus sed temporibus quidem, voluptatum veniam debitis error, sit id quod quae alias, expedita corporis soluta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima voluptatem, facilis, nisi harum qui quibusdam asperiores excepturi facere dolor eveniet enim praesentium voluptates. Recusandae, voluptatibus sed temporibus quidem, voluptatum veniam debitis error, sit id quod quae alias, expedita corporis soluta.</p>
  </section>
</body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Codepen you've created doesn't include Bootstrap JS which is required for the Scrollspy component. Also the `.active` class would be set in CSS, not the `:active` state.

```
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active,
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
  color: #59abe3;
}
```

Codeply: https://www.codeply.com/go/31pbFXSYkg